# Game would not run in game maker and it said "cannot use function/script name for a variable,using"motion_add"

Tags: gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-studio-1.4

this was happening to me as I tried to make an astroids game on game maker. I put in the code `motion_add[image_angle, 0.2]` and it was working fine then it said

> "cannot use function/script name for a variable,using"motion_add"

if you guys could help me I would be grateful thank you.

Comment: Hi new GML user! If your question was answered, could you please mark the answer as such? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the motion_add() function. The syntax should be

```
motion_add(image_angle, 0.2);
```

when you use the " [   ] " symbols for the arguments, as you did, you are telling Game Maker to look for the data in the "motion_add" array at the coordinates "image_angle" and "0.2". That is not what you want. Also, do not forget the ";" at the end of your line.

Comment: hey thanks but I tried running the game again and I it says "error in object obj_spaceship,event up, action 1 at line 1, position 11:assinment operator expected and obj_spaceship is my sprite

Comment: Does your "UP" event contains more than this this line ? (If it's the case, post the full event code please.)  And I believe obj_spaceship is more likely to be an object than a sprite.
This new error is different, maybe you should ask it in a new question ?

Comment: that line is the only code I had for the up event and  by ask it a new question do you mean use a different event or code

Comment: Do you have a ; at the end of your line ?

Comment: Yes, you need one :)

Comment: At the end of the line.